# Twilio "0.11.1" getmessages with "anchor" parameter not working

Tags: javascript, c#, twilio

We are migrating from javascript ipmessaging api version "0.1.5" to "0.11.1". We have been using "channel.getMessagesPaged" which is replaced by "channel.getMessages" in new javascript api.

Problem : The method call with passing parameter "anchor" has started failing now.

We tried to refer the following migration [guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/migration-guide-javascript-0110).
The given link doesn't mention a changes in parameters for getMessages from getMessagesPaged.

Earlier, we have been passing the earliest message sid as the "anchor" value and keeping it same. We also followed the comments in un-minified(debug) version. (ref: releases/0.11.1/twilio-chat.js)

For your reference:

- Returns last messages from channel

  - @param {String} [anchor] Most early message id which is already known, or 'end' by default

Every time, we are trying to call method getMessages() with anchor value, we are receiving following exception: "Invalid 'From' query parameter value. Expected an integer"
Full exception for reference:

[image]

Please look at the screen-cast above and help us know if we are missing something here.

It would be great if you provide us some reference for this method with anchor value.

Comment: Could you share the code you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchor was update to be the message index instead of message SID.

So it's not a string anymore, but integer.

Migration doc updated to reflect this explicitly: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/migration-guide-javascript-0110#anchor-for-message-paging-changed-type

Also note that there are two methods for getMessages in js bundle; one is external and another one is internal. You are referring to internal one in your question which really has string as anchor. But it's not a public API.

It's better to check API docs for that: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.12.0/docs/